# No-allocation copying from Span<byte> into the unmanaged memory (IntPtr)

Tags: c#, interop

I have preallocated `Span<byte>` and unmanaged memory pointed by `IntPtr` and I want to copy contents from the `Span` into unmanaged memory.
I would like to avoid additional allocations and `unsafe` context.

The task looks pretty simple, but I found that `Marshal.Copy` only supports copying from `byte[]` and can't process `Span` in any way. So, with `Marshal.Copy` I ended up with a following code, which envolves an intermediate allocation of `byte[]`

```
    Span<byte> src = GetSpan();
    IntPtr dst = GetUnmanagedMemoryPointer();
    byte[] tmp = src.ToArray();
    Marshal.Copy(tmp, 0, dst, src.Length);
```

The other way I found is to wrap the unmanaged memory with the `Span`, but this envolves `unsafe`

```
    Span<byte> src = GetSpan();
    IntPtr dst = GetUnmanagedMemoryPointer();
    
    Span<byte> dstSpan;
    unsafe
    {
        dstSpan = new Span<byte>(dst.ToPointer(), src.Length);
    }
    src.CopyTo(dstSpan);
```

Both variants works, but both are non-perfect.
So, can we perform direct copy from `Span` into unmanaged memory without `unsafe` context and/or additional intermediate allocations?

Comment: "The unsafe keyword denotes an unsafe context, which is required for any operation involving pointers." As I understand it, regarding your final questions, no, we can't.

Comment: What would you like to do with the unmanaged memory once you have it? The `Marhsal` has a lot of powerful tools for most common requirements.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood I getting the unmanaged pointer from 3rd party C++ library and I need to fill it with data from 3rd party C# library (which gives me a `Span`) for future processing on the C++ side.

Comment: Agree for a case with manual pointers manipulations. But in the particular case this looks like a little bit inconsistent for me. `Marshal.Copy` can perfectly work with `byte[] & IntPtr` without `unsafe`, but can't do the same with `Span & IntPtr`. Wierd...

Comment: I see what you're saying but it's because `Marshal` is doing the `unsafe` bit for you outside of your code. Checking the source now, it seems to use external Win32 to execute the copies. I'm afraid you'll need to either stay "managed" and accept the allocation, or go "unsafe".

Comment: Is there any way of getting `GetUnmanagedMemoryPointer` to return either a `ref byte` or a `Span<byte>`?

Comment: @Charlieface, I don't think so. The existing C++-to-C# bindings, provided with the C++ library, does not provide such a functionality. The ways to workaround the existing wrapper and getting pointer directly in a desirable format are likely possible with reflection or something like this, but I'm afrarid such a ways will kill any performance benefits which is possible do get due to avoided allocations (and also will likely involve `unsafe` context too). On the other hand, it is easy to get `ref byte` from `Span<byte>`, but it looks useless for the current task.

Comment: You could easily write a DLL in raw CIL instructions, with a function that took a `IntPtr` and returned a `ref byte` or `Span<byte>`, but that's the same as doing `unsafe` I suppose.